# Problem at executing Automated test over Azuredevops pipeline with Katalon extension

Tags: azure-devops, katalon-studio

Right now I am trying to execute Katalon extension over azure pipeline where a build and publish phase has been completed and there is just left a katalon test execution. The problem is that I´ve tried to execute a test (on katalon extension) that I´ve created on katalon studio but it last so much time and never gets completed (Even with a simple test like enter to a page and close browser).

[Testing in progress on katalon extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPyqg.png)

The previous steps I tried for creating this test execution are the next:

1. I Created a test suit on katalon studio and prove it (it gets
   executed succesfully).
2. I Generate a command for CMD and copied
       arguments.
3. I created a task on pipeline phase for executing katalon
       extension on Azure devops with the next set of options.

[Katalon Extension Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l62FB.png)

Then I execute the phase, and Katalon task never gets completed (I wait over 30 minutes or so … even with a simple test like sending a POST request to an API).

I also tried to set Download katalon instead of using a preinstalled one

[Katalon extension configuration with katalon download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8kSi.png)

Please, I would like to know if there is some problem with the arguments I am setting or what other thing I am missing.